# How do I get a result set from a table and its child-tables?

Tags: mysql

According to an ER Model, there is a table `Task` and it has 8 child-tables. Each of those child tables have different attributes according to its type, for example the task table would look as follows (the real ER Model has more attributes in task table)

```
Task_ID | Version | Title | Place | Reason | Description
```

And one of its child tables would look like this

```
Task_ID | Version | Begin | End
```

Another one like this

```
Task_ID | Version | Begin | Duration | Duration_unit
```

Lets say we create a new Task with Begin and End, we perform 2 inserts, no problem with that. But what about if I want to get all the tasks from all the different task types? For example Task with ID=1, how would the `SELECT` statement look like? I tried doint a select like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TASK,TASK_1,TASK_2,TASK_3,TASK_4,TASK_5,TASK6,TASK_7,TASK_8;
```

I tested inserting into `TASK` and `TASK4`, but whenever i try that select it does not show anything, and putting a where causes an ambiguos column error. I thought about making a big `JOIN` but I dont know if that would be efficient. I also want to take out null value columns

Comment: _ambiguos column error._ 3 tables have the same column name. So a `SELECT *` needs to be more specific

Comment: For example I need to get the ID, Version, Title, Place, Reason, Description, begin and end of a task in one select, I tried `SELECT ID,Version,Title,Place,Reason,Description,Begin,End fromTASK,TASK_1,TASK_2,TASK_3,TASK_4,TASK_5,TASK6,TASK_7,TASK_8; ` and still got the ambiguos error

Comment: You say there are 8, but only describe 2. What might another 1 look like?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by null  value columns.  But you can include a `WHERE` clause to reduce the result set to exclude rows with null values in a column.

```
select t.*, ct.Begin, ct.End, ct2.Duration, ct2.Duration_unit
from task t
join childTask ct
on t.Task_ID=ct.Task_ID
join childTask2 ct2
on ct2.Task_ID=ct.Task_ID
```